# How does pinax learn to access css files in accounts basic project?

Tags: django, pinax

I just started using Pinax 0.9a2. Basic configuration, and deployed the "accounts" project. I observed that in the installed applications I have "pinax_theme_bootstrap". The main page correctly shows up, with the css for the basic application theme. If I browse the page source, among the various stuff, I have this for the css

http://localhost:8000/site_media/static/css/bootstrap.min.css

The point is that I can't find anywhere where this line comes from, nor how it's actually served. I understand it is probably generated by the pinax_theme_bootstrap application, but I don't understand: how is this application supposed to operate, if there's no urls.py in it to resolve the above line and deliver the file?

The file is present and in full path here

```
MacQuela:~/Work/Projects/test/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pinax_theme_bootstrap/static/css $ ls
bootstrap.min.css extra.css
```

This is the settings.py when it comes to static declarations

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "site_media", "static")

# URL that handles the static files like app media.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com"
STATIC_URL = "/site_media/static/"

# Additional directories which hold static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static"),
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
    "staticfiles.finders.LegacyAppDirectoriesFinder",
    "compressor.finders.CompressorFinder",
]
```

Nowhere is specified where pinax can find that css.

Comment: Why does it need a urls.py for that app? Its referencing the main STATIC_URL/STATIC_ROOT option in your settings.py . It expects to find that file in your static location.

Comment: @jdi: that's the point. How does it find them? those files are not in the STATIC_ROOT. They are hidden in the pinax_theme_bootstrap, which is in lib/python2.6/site-packages/pinax_theme_bootstrap/

Comment: Also, I don't get it. How are you supposed to use an app, if you don't have a urls.py ? I don't understand the mechanism. The tutorial presents only apps where you have an urls.py which you use to access views. It never presents an app without that schema.

Comment: pinax_theme_bootstrap doesn't have any of its own views. It just provides a chain of templates and you are supposed to extend from its theme_base.html. There isn't supposed to be a urls.py for it nor a view.py

Comment: @jdi: ok, but still, how does he know where to fetch that css file from ? I can't see where this is specified.

Comment: Well I see that pinax_theme_bootstrap does contain the css file in an un-minified format. Are you running a type of `statics*` app that automatically minifies? That would end up transforming that already existing css reference to the `.min.css` version

Answer (score 2):

My comments ended up getting long under your question so I decided to try and take a swing at an answer.

bootstrap.css is included with pinax_theme_bootstrap app, as you can see in the theme_base.html template: https://github.com/pinax/pinax-theme-bootstrap/blob/master/pinax_theme_bootstrap/templates/theme_base.html

Its referencing the django static location which is resolved from your settings.py options. Now the fact that you are actually seeing a minified version of this file in a slightly modified location leads me to believe that you have another django static* app that performs minification of css/js for you. Most likely its the `compressor` app that is minifiying.

**update**

The part that is confusing you is actually how django serves static files: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

There is no black magic here. Its very straightforward. Every app in your project can contain its own static/ directory which will contain static media for that app. You will notice in your settings.py and also in that link above that there is a combination of the STATIC options and the other includes like the finders. These will locate the static media under each app. And it also allows apps to not have to know the entire absolute url. Instead they can use {{STATIC}} in the templates to get the root location.

Now when you run your dev server using 'runserver' it will resolve all that static media for you. This is why the bootstrap css is being found. Ita being referenced in the theme_base.html as a static url.

When you are ready for production you obviously will no longer be using the django dev server. You will then end up running a command like  './manage.py collectstatic' which will round up all the static media into a single location that you can then server through your web server of choice. I hope this clears it up for you. Its better to review the django docs about this since pinax is django.

Answer (score 1):

1. Pinax use [django-staticfiles](https://github.com/jezdez/django-staticfileshttps://stackoverflow.com/posts/9170369/edit) serve the static files.  You can find the `STATIC_ROOT`, `STATICFILES_DIRS`, `STATICFILES_FINDERS` variables in the `settings.py`.
2. In Pinax account base project's `url.py`, you can find the line like this:`url(r"", include("staticfiles.urls"))`, it's define the static file access.
3. Get a better view, `django-statifiles` overwrite the Django default `runserver` command under the Debug mode, it's rewrite the Django defualt `WSGIHandler` with `StatifFilesHandler`. So when you run `python manage.py  runserver` and access the site, it will determine whether the request is a static file request, if true, it's find the file stored in the `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting(using `staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder`) and a `static`  subdirectory of each app(using `staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder`) in `INSTALLED_APPS`.
4. Here, the `pinax_theme_bootstrap` is a Django app only include static files under `static` directory and default installed by pinax account base project. The static files access is resolved by `staticfiles` app,  so you can't find any `urls.py` file under `pinax_theme_bootstrap`.
5. When  you want to deploy your project to a product environment. You should use `python manage.py collectstatic`  command to collect all your useful static files under the `STATIC_ROOT` directory. And then you can serve this directory by Nginx or other http server.

---

When you access http://localhost:8000/site_media/static/css/bootstrap.min.css, then Django will match this url in the `urls.py`, every specific config will doesn't match until the last `staticfiles` config. So this access will be resolved by `staticfiles`. According your `STATICFILES_FINDER` config,  `staticfiles` find  the `static` directory under your  project first, if result is none, then it will find every subdirectory named `static` in  `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Still I don't get it, where does pinax_theme_boostrap communicate where its static files are ? There's too much black magic going on here.

Comment: @StefanoBorini The static files is in a directory named `static` under every Django apps after  you set `staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder` .